# Generating all contiguous sublists of a list

Tags: list, haskell, sublist

I'm kinda new to Haskell and I'm trying to generate all contiguous sublists of a list.

I current have the following:

```
listSublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
listSublists []     = [[]]
listSublists xs     = [xs] ++ listSublists (init xs)
```

I know the function above would generate sublists with the last element removed but I've no idea how to finish my pseudocode.

My pseudocode is basically,

> Take the whole complete list, remove tail. Pass xs of (x:xs) into
>   listSublists

For example, xs = [1,2,3]
[xs] ++ listSublists (init xs) would generate [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2], [1], [] and I'm trying to continue that with passing in [2,3,4] as xs until the list is exhausted.

Can someone give me some pointers? Or am I thinking in a completely wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listSublists` function that you have is functionally almost identical to
the [`inits`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3ainits)
function. You are on the right track, in that you can currently list all of
the prefixes of a given list.

What you want to ask is "what is a sublist of a list?" One answer is that it
is a suffix of a prefix of the list (i.e. chop off some portion from the
end of a list and then chop off some elements off the front of that list, and
you have one of the contiguous sublists).

So, if you have your `prefixes`, then what you want is a way to generate all
the suffixes of a given prefix (i.e. of some list). So, if you have

```
prefixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
prefixes []     = [[]]
prefixes xs     = [xs] ++ prefixes (init xs)
```

you also want a corresponding function `suffixes`

```
suffixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
suffixes []     = [[]]
suffixes xs     = [xs] ++ suffixes (??? xs)
```

I will leave it to you to figure out what to use for `???`. With these two
functions, you then just take all the prefixes, and produce all the suffixes
to get all the contiguous sublists

```
allSublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
allSublists = concat . map suffixes . prefixes
```

You may want to remove all of the empty lists that will be in the result set,
as they are not that interesting of a case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I'm suppose to use tail for ??? but I don't really get the `concat . map suffixes . prefixes` part. I'm not entirely sure on how to properly write it.

Comment: @user1043625 I am not sure what you mean. That is how you would write it. Unless you want to know how to write the list functions therein. Otherwise, it is just a composition of functions.

Comment: I believe I misunderstood some parts of your answer but I believe I figured it out. I'm actually doing it it a different way. `listSuffix(xs) ++ listPrefix(init xs)`. Now I need to find a way to remove duplicates of the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

All sublists (not necessarily contiguous):

```
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = [x:sublist | sublist <- sublists xs] ++ sublists xs
```

Only contiguous sublists:

```
nub $ concat $ map tails $ inits ls
```

or

```
(:) [] $ filter (\x -> length x /= 0) $ concat $ map tails $ inits ls
```